# How to put each element of array into table row - table data?

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting String from txt file, and then explode to get format below.

```
$array = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    foreach($array as $arr) {
    print_r(explode(";",$arr));
}
```

**Output is:**

```
Array ( [0] => miha [1] => dasjkhdkasjhdjkashdjka [2] => Paracinac [3] => Kupus, Krastavac, Majonez, Vegeta, Aleva, Tartar [4] => dasdas ) 
Array ( [0] => miha [1] => dasjkhdkasjhdjkashdjka [2] => Paracinac [3] => Kupus, Krastavac, Majonez, Vegeta, Aleva, Tartar [4] => dasdas )
```

INFO: txt file will have lots of data since its add dynamically by users inputs so ill have like 30 arrays every day.

Now i am trying to make a table, one row for each array and table data for every element of array.
I tryed code:

```
foreach ($array as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['0'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['1'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['2'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['3'] . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $row['4'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

And i am getting out put like

```
m   i   h   a   ;
m   i   h   a   ;
```

So i noticed that $row['0']... 0 is point of first character of first element in array but i need full value.

Comment: you forgot explode $row in your second loop ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store exploded array in any array then you need to access that array, Try:

```
$loopArr = array();
$array = file('test.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($array as $arr) {
    $loopArr[] = explode(";",$arr); // first create array of all exploded data
}

if(!empty($loopArr)) { // loop through that array
    foreach($loopArr as $arrInner) { // display data inside
        echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>' . $arrInner['0'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $arrInner['1'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $arrInner['2'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $arrInner['3'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . $arrInner['4'] . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Wors very fine. Thxs